# Unable to make request in node.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am using the following code in the controller by CCAvenue but I get an error

> TypeError: request.on is not a function

Below is the code for the request

```
    request.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log("data is ----------------> " + data);
        body += data;
        encRequest = ccav.encrypt(body, workingKey);
        console.log("Enc request " + encRequest);
        formbody = '<form id="nonseamless" method="post" name="redirect" action="https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction"/> <input type="hidden" id="encRequest" name="encRequest" value="' + encRequest + '"><input type="hidden" name="access_code" id="access_code" value="' + accessCode + '"><script language="javascript">document.redirect.submit();</script></form>';
    });

    request.on('end', function () {
        response.writeHeader(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        response.write(formbody);
        response.end();
    });
```

I am including the request using `var request = require('request')`

Edit:

```
request.post("https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction", {
        form: {
            encRequest: encRequest,
            access_code: accessCode
        }
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

I get a response in my body which is an html page. How do I send it back to the browser in sail.js framework ?

Edit 2 :
I've tried using sails.request method too but there is no response.

```
var payReq = {
        url: "https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
            // "Content-Type": 'application/json'
        },
        // data : {
        //     encRequest: encRequest,
        //     access_code: accessCode
        // }
        data : `encRequest=${encRequest}&access_code=${accessCode}`

    }
    sails.request(payReq);
```

Comment: `.on` should be initialized after setting the URL, So please send us the complete query so we can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using Request in an incorrect way.. this pattern you're using would work for the HTTP/HTTPS libraries. Here's a Request example.

```
var request = require('request');

var options = {
    url: "https://httpbin.org/ip",
    method: "get"
};

console.log('Requesting IP..');
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('error:', error);
    } else {
        console.log('Response: Headers:', response && response.headers);
    }
});
```

The request.on('data' .. pattern is used by the Native HTTP and HTTPs libraries. examples would be here:

https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html

This page includes examples using Request, HTTP, Axios.

Comment: You were right, thanks ! Can you please check the edit and help me with that ?

Comment: Sure thing, will do!

Comment: Thanks ! FYI, I want to make an external request to ccavenue which redirects me to the payment page !

Comment: Can you use res.send (body) to send the response?

Comment: Yeah ! I did that and it just gives me bare bone html .
Respone:- https://ibb.co/izWD58